# How to rotate source video in Movie Clip Editor - Blender 2.68

Tags: tracking, video

After importing my footage in to the Movie Clip Editor, I find that it is not oriented the way I would like.

[image]

What is the easiest way to rotate this in Blender?

Comment: This video worked for me https://youtu.be/hfo-DRGvkgo

Comment: The guy has an updated version of how to do this in Blender 2.80 and up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wc6ZCjRZadk

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could add a transformation strip ([effect](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/strips/effects/introduction.html)) in the VSE and set the rotation. See the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/strips/effects/transform.html) for further details on available settings.

[image]

Comment: OK, but will this also rotate the movie that I see in Movie Clip Editor? As I need to add my track markers there.

Comment: @Neil You could try rendering the video out to a file from the VSE, then loading it into the movieclip editor. I don't know of any way to go directly from the VSE to the movie clip editor, but I don't use these much so I may just be missing something.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to do this IN blender, just need to remember to change the Resolution settings after rotation, this isn't done automatically.

Comment: The vse also has x and y flip states in strip properties. Better quality than a rotate effect. Would be nice if movie clip editor had this as well as the aspect ratio controls.

Comment: This dead link only answer is exactly why link only answers should always be removed. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @Rob I sure understand the whole link only thing (and I'm one that is constantly reminding people of it). However, in this case don't you think it was a bit overkill to flag it? You may or may not know that blender changed its manual, breaking **all** the links. This is normal, and pretty easy to fix the link. But aside from that, even without the link I still understood what to do. There was still an answer here; and that is the difference between a link only answer and an answer with a dead link.

Comment: @David Without the link, you're left with a picture. You can't search pictures so the answer is not discoverable. As one who is new to Blender, I don't understand much of the picture either so, to me, there is no answer here.

Comment: That is not quite all that is left. It says use a "transformation strip" and set it to "rotate" that *is* the answer. The picture just shows where the buttons are. Sorry to disappoint, but the manual is not going to be much more help here.

Comment: @Rob  If someone has the same question he will find the answer, searching for an answer you don't know doesn't make much sense. By the way  complains and critique is probably not the best way to join a community.

Comment: @David I see the rules for posting with images are not the same as Stackoverflow and other stackexchanges where such posting is restricted or prohibited. My concerns are valid for the same reasons other exchanges do not allow such posting but I would remove my flag if I could because, here, it's not against the rules.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out, but you may also need to rescale (I did). Ensure that your render output resolution is your desired output resolution first, then in "scale x" I put 1920/1080 and in "scale y" I put 1080/1920 and then the video's aspect ratio is correct (I was going from 1920x1080 input on its side to 1080x1920 output the correct way round)

Comment: The picture was enough information for me to figure out the answer.

Comment: Although its solved the problem, but in my  case it has a side effect, i.e. it reduce quality, so after a lot of search i end up with avidemux->Filter->Rorate 90 degree->save

Answer (score 2):

### In Blender 2.9

- Select Video
- `Shift-A` --> `Effect Strip` --> `Transform`

[image: Add Transform Effect to VSE Clip in Blender 2.9]

- `Strip Tab` --> `Rotation` --> `90`

[image: Add Rotation Transform to VSE in Blender 2.9]

---

To "Flip" the footage, use `TRANSFORM` --> `MIRROR` --> `X & Y` like so:

[image: Blender 2.8 Transform Mirror on X Y axis]

Transform footage mirroring X & Y turns it "right side" up:

[image: Blender 2.8 Transform Mirror X Y axis]

Comment: This will only flip the source, not rotate it 90deg which is what I needed.